# How to properly set a Datagrid's ContextMenu's databinding (MVVM Light)

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, mvvm-light

Can someone please take a look at my XAML and please tell me why the command on my MenuItem does not work.  I assume there is an error in my DataGrid's Tag binding, however, I can't seem to wrap my head around what is going on.

On a side note I understand that context menus do not share the same visual tree.  I also understand if I set the ContextMenu DataContext to that of the Window, everything works as expected.  I'm trying to understand why my PlacementTarget.Tag binding does not work as expected.  Thanks in advance.

The view looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
        xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <ContextMenu x:Key="Context"
                            DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding OpenCommand, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource Context}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The viewmodel

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            if (IsInDesignMode)
            {
                // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
            }
            else
            {
                // Code runs "for real"
                People = new ObservableCollection<Person>
                {
                    new Person { FirstName = "Tim",  },
                    new Person { FirstName = "Todd" },
                    new Person { FirstName = "Jane" },
                    new Person { FirstName = "Doe" },
                };
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

        private RelayCommand _openCommand;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the OpenCommand.
        /// </summary>
        public RelayCommand OpenCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _openCommand
                    ?? (_openCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    () =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("YES!");
                    }));
            }
        }
    }
```

and model

```
public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

    }
```

and some Debug info

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=18243409) for Binding (hash=24719867)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'OpenCommand'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.Command (hash=668104)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Found data context element: MenuItem (hash=668104) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Found data context element: MenuItem (hash=668104) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Found data context element: MenuItem (hash=668104) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Found data context element: MenuItem (hash=668104) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Found data context element: MenuItem (hash=668104) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Resolving source  (last chance)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Found data context element: MenuItem (hash=668104) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): Activate with root item <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 106 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409):   Item at level 0 is null - no accessor
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): TransferValue - got raw value {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 88 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): TransferValue - using fallback/default value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=18243409): TransferValue - using final value <null>
```